# How do you delete achieve log image copies that are already backed up?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

How do you delete achieve log image copies that are already backed up ?

It seems like below command doesn't work:

```
delete copy of archivelog all until time 'sysdate-1' backed up 1 times to disk
```

Comment: Can you provide the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

`all` and `until time` does not work together, choose one:

```
delete copy of archivelog until time 'sysdate-1' backed up 1 times to disk;
```

or

```
delete copy of archivelog all backed up 1 times to disk;
```